# Plotting the "relation" of two functions dependent values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm trying to device or find a method that allows me to plot the ratio values (I cannot think of the correct words for this) of two functions to plot against one another.

For example, it would be like for finding the roots of two functions that have of two dependent variables `x` and `y` f(x) = g(y). But I would want to plot the relationship between `x` and `y` based on their functions.

For example:

[image]

It would be like trying to see where these values match for the same N(>M_h) = N(>M_star). See where their x values (which is cut off from this image) match for their matching y values, and then plot their relationship, such as M_h(M_star) or M_star(M_h).

I do not have any example code for this unfortunately because I have no idea on how to start a method like this.

If their is a need for more elaboration, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting the relationship between two independend variables `x` and `y` conditioned on the functions `f(x)` and `g(y)` can be done by plotting a contour at `f(x)-g(y) = 0`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: x**2
g = lambda y: np.sqrt(y)

x = np.linspace(0,2,101)
y = np.linspace(0,10,101)

fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10,4))

ax.plot(x, f(x))
ax.plot([1.5],[f(1.5)], marker="o")
ax2.plot(y, g(y))
ax2.plot([f(1.5)**2],[f(1.5)], marker="o")

#create a meshgrid from the x and y array
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
#plot the contour f(X)-g(Y) = 0
c = ax3.contour(X,Y, f(X)-g(Y), 0)
ax3.plot([1.5],[f(1.5)**2], marker="o")

ax.set_ylim([0,4])
ax2.set_ylim([0,4])
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("f(x)")
ax2.set_xlabel("y")
ax2.set_ylabel("g(y)")
ax3.set_xlabel("x")
ax3.set_ylabel("y")

ax3.legend(handles=[c.collections[0]], labels=["f(x) = g(y)"])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```